# Duplicate Converters error in Windows Phone 7 XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

In a Windows Phone 7 project I'm using XAML that looks like this;

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ValueConverters:FuelTypeEnumToRadioButtonConverter x:Name="fuelConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and further down on my Page I'm using it like this:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding PreferredFuel, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Blyfri95, Converter={StaticResource fuelConverter}}"  Content="Blyfri 95" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,276,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="FuelType" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding PreferredFuel, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Blyfri98, Converter={StaticResource fuelConverter}}" Content="Blyfri 98" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,276,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="FuelType" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding PreferredFuel, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Diesel, Converter={StaticResource fuelConverter}}" Content="Diesel" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="308,276,0,0" Name="radioButton3" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="FuelType" />
```

This all works fine and dandy in the actual application, but the XAML editor in Visual Studio complains that "**Cannot register duplicate Name 'fuelConverter' in this scope**". I have to comment out the initial Resource-line to get the XAML designer working in Visual Studio 2010 (but then the application doesn't work when I run it).

Anyone else seen this? Is this just a bug with the XAML designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shouldn't that be:

```
<ValueConverters:FuelTypeEnumToRadioButtonConverter x:Key="fuelConverter" />
```

using `x:Key` instead of `x:Name` ?

Not sure why you get that error, though.

Comment: You are absolutely right! When I used x:Name on the ValueConverter definition I got the duplicate warning when I had two things further down in my XAML that used the converter. When I changed it to x:Key it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your code you use **x:Name**,

If there is a resource or any named variable share this name you get this error on design time but works fine on runtime. This is reality!

I got this error on silverlight desings because myUserControl and Resource name is common so I changed **x:Name** attribute to **x:Key** for userControl then fixed! works fine now.

I hope this helps.